# Why is my system using port 4?

Tags: windows-7, internet, port

I have Windows 7 and have noticed that my system is using port 4 to connect to a lot of different IP addresses. When it connects to them it is not for very long before it moves to another IP address.

One night I sat and wrote down as many as I could and started checking whois to see where they were and they were from all over the world. I don't understand this.

When I did a search on the net with this question. The only info I could come up with was, that port 4 is used by the US Army and a list of port assignments listed it as "unassigned".
If anyone has any clues to what is going on... I would greatly appreciate any info I could get.

Comment: [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) can show the actual data that is being transferred. Is this source or destination port 4? TCP or UDP? Either way, it might be a sign of malware, since most newly-written programs avoid using low ports.

Comment: What did you use to check? netstat -b should give you an idea what software is using the port

Comment: [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) (part of the free [Sysinternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb842062)) can be very helpful to find out what application is using/listening on which ports.

Comment: Port 4 of what protocol?  udp, tcp, icmp (type), ipv4 encapsulation (ip protocol 4)?  You say "using port 4" - using implies source port, or is it connecting to port 4?  If you can post what you are seeing ([edit]) it will help narrow it down.

Comment: Outgoing connections are not made from root ports.

Answer (score 0):

Conjecture: Malware or botnet is contacting a Command/Control Server.

Other possibilities:
  Undocumented functionality in windows is engaged in some sort of behavior.  You can probably stop outgoing connections to port4 with a firewall, but I suggest you use an external firewall to configure the block.

As in the comments above: You might learn a lot by reading the data using wireshark.